# SSH: Could not resolve hostname user@host: Name or service not known with my connection

Tags: wireless, networking, server, ssh, dns

I have a problem to connect a server using ssh. I got the following error message:

```
ssh user@host 
SSH: Could not resolve hostname  user@host: Name or service not known with my connection
```

Also, if I try to use ping I have an error too:

```
ping: unknown host
```

But ping with another server works:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (203.211.0.99) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 203.211.0.99: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=8.68 ms
……
```

Also, I have these error only when I try to connect from home. When I use a connection from another place, I have no problem. So I suppose it's linked to my network, but I don't really know where to look at...

Here are some informations that may help you:

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1 
search hitronhub.home
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   natahem

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Could it be possible you've entered the wrong host? Or is the host address blocked by your router? Also possibly blocked by your routers firewall

Comment: Did you literally enter `user@host` or did replace `user` and `host` with your actual username and the real hostname?

Comment: You have to be more detail on this issue. Are you using the same PC at home & work?? which host ping shows unknown & which resolves? As you say, you use another connection from another place, it works.. is it through another different workstation... etc. Making your question more clear will help us to understand and assist properly.

Comment: Yes I use the same computer at work and at home. The wireless network change though.
I didn't type literally "user@host" of course. I typed the right user and host (because it's working when using my work network). And the problem appears on several host I used to connect without any problem before. 
All the associated ping are not resolve (but when I try to use ping with another host, like google.com, it's working)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, things are working now.

It seems it was a problem of connection. I reboot everything, and now it's solved!

Comment: Please mark as solved.